# cannot install aws-sam-cli on macos catalina with brew gdbm not present or broken

Tags: aws-sam-cli

Following instructions on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-mac.html:

```
    (venv) dougbergh@192 de % brew install aws-sam-cli
    Updating Homebrew...
    ==> Installing aws-sam-cli from aws/tap
    ==> Downloading https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases/download/v0.48.0//aws-sam-cli-0.49.0.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
    #=#=-#  #                                                                     
    curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
    Error: Failed to download resource "aws-sam-cli"
    Download failed: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases/download/v0.48.0//aws-sam-cli-0.49.0.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
    Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
    Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
      RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/gdbm not present or broken
    Please reinstall gdbm. Sorry :(
    (venv) dougbergh@192 de % python --version
    Python 3.8.1
```

I can find nothing about installing gdbm...but hopefully the easier path is to resolve the 404 & install from the bottle. Any insights?

Answer (score 2):

Issue with installer; see https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1987. Presumably there will be a fix; a workaround is suggested at that site.